# Using .set on a filtered array of IDs in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I used Underscore.js's `_.filter` to get an array of object ids like so:

```
var downstreamMeters = _.filter(that.collection.models, function(item) { return item.get("isdownstreammeter"); });
```

Now I want to set a certain attribute of each model in the array. I thought it would make sense to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < downstreamMeters.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    inputMeters = downstreamMeters[i].get("inputmeters");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputMeters.length; i++) {
        var flow = parseFloat(that.collection.get(inputMeters[i]).get("adjustedflow"));
        sum += flow;
    }
    downstreamMeters[i].set({incrementalflow: sum});
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

I checked the `downstreamMeters` array and it has the right objects in it. What do I need to do to set the attribute for each model in the array?

Comment: Check if your `downstreamMeters` array has any element in it.

Comment: What you're showing works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/D4bT3/). Is the "Some code..." changing `i` or `downstreamMeters` in any way?

Comment: @muistooshort It appears that what I had as `\\ Some code` _is_ causing problems. I updated the `\\ Some code` to what it actually is, which is a for loop. Is it a bad idea to put a for loop in another for loop? I'm new to JS and thought it would achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying `for(var i = 0; ...)` is somewhat misleading. JavaScript hoists all `var` declarations up to the top of the closest scope and `for` loop doesn't create its own scope. The result is that this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < downstreamMeters.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    inputMeters = downstreamMeters[i].get("inputmeters");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputMeters.length; i++) {
        var flow = parseFloat(that.collection.get(inputMeters[i]).get("adjustedflow"));
        sum += flow;
    }
    downstreamMeters[i].set({incrementalflow: sum});
}
```

is the same as this:

```
var i, sum, flow;
for (i = 0; i < downstreamMeters.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    inputMeters = downstreamMeters[i].get("inputmeters");
    for (i = 0; i < inputMeters.length; i++) {
        flow = parseFloat(that.collection.get(inputMeters[i]).get("adjustedflow"));
        sum += flow;
    }
    downstreamMeters[i].set({incrementalflow: sum});
}
```

Now you can see that you are using exactly the same `i` in the outer and inner loops. On the first run through the loop, `i` will be `inputMeters.length` when you say `downstreamMeters[i].set(...)`. Apparently, `inputMeters.length > downstreamMeters.length` so you end up running off the end of `downstreamMeters`; if you try to access an element of an array that is past the array's end, you get `undefined` and there's your

> Cannot call method 'set' of undefined.

error.

Nesting loops is fine but you should be using different variables:

```
var i, j, sum, inputMeters;
for (i = 0; i < downstreamMeters.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    inputMeters = downstreamMeters[i].get("inputmeters");
    for (j = 0; j < inputMeters.length; j++)
        sum += parseFloat(that.collection.get(inputMeters[j]).get("adjustedflow"));
    downstreamMeters[i].set({incrementalflow: sum});
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a bunch! I did some debugging and inputMeters.length was indeed greater than downstreamMeters.length.

Comment: @chrishenn: And if it wasn't, your outer loop would never finish.